# Angular handle $http.head

Tags: angularjs

When using angular's $http.head(), it returns a status. When the item does not exist, I get a 404 error in my console.

How do I catch this error and take action when the status is 200 and take no action otherwise?

Comment: are you using `.then` to resolve the promise  `$http.head('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Comment: Yes I am using .then(data=>{},err=>{})

Comment: If my answer sufficiently answered your question can you please mark it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This should give the functionality you are looking for:

```
var successCallback = function(response) {
 //do your stuff when successful (status 200)

}

var errorCallback = function(response) {
 //do your stuff when there is an error (400, 404 ect..)

} 
$http.head('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

As far as suppressing the error itself from showing up in your console, I believe that is just a browser functionality.